# Create a custom Facebook Share link

Tags: facebook, html, fb.ui

So this question has been asked before, but no one wants to do it in the manner that I want to, so bear with me while I try and explain. The FB.ui API has some functions that I find useful, mainly that I can dynamically change the description. So, I want to put the FB.ui into a link that a user can click and then a pop up will appear where they can share my webpage. So far what I have is:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
 function shareFB(){

      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '42352352356463',
          status     : true,
          xfbml      : true
        });
        FB.ui(
  {
   method: 'feed',
   name: 'name',
   caption: 'caption',
   description: (

    a
   ),
   link: 'http://www.image.com/',
   picture: 'http://www.image.com/static/3.png'
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
      alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

}
</script>
```

and then I have a link to this here:

```
<a class="links" onclick='shareFB()' href="#"> Share! </a>
```

But this doesn't work. Why not!

Comment: Can you be more specific than "doesn't work"?

Comment: Nothing happens when I click the link.

Comment: You need to be more specific than that - what do you get in your console when you troubleshoot? What happens when you debug and step through your code?

Comment: How can I troubleshoot through this, or debug and step through it? All I know is to try it and if it doesn't work then to try something else lol.

Comment: ^^ Sorry, but that's out of scope for StackOverflow. This is just JavaScript, so you can just search for "debug javascript" to get you started. (you really should be proficient at debugging in general if you wish to be a developer)

Comment: Why do you wrap everything in one single function?

Comment: because I want to call on that single function with an onclick. I basically want a custom trigger to call on FB.ui, because if I don't wrap it into a function then it is automatically called when the page loads. And I don't want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading the facebook SDK when you click the button and that's the wrong way to load it, change your script to this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '42352352356463', // App ID
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });
};


// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_PT/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));


function shareFB(){
    var obj = {
        method: 'feed',
        name: 'name',
        caption: 'caption',
        description: 'description',
        link: 'http://www.image.com/',
        picture: 'http://www.image.com/static/3.png'
    };

    function share(response){
        if (response && response.post_id) {
          alert('Post was published.');
        } else {
          alert('Post was not published.');
        }
    }
    FB.ui(obj, share);
};
</script>
```